# How to enable ClientCache in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-core, clientcache

In ASP.net 4.5 we used to be able to enable expires headers on static resources (in-turn, enabling browser caching) by adding 'ClientCache' to the web.config, something like:

```
<staticcontent>
  <clientcache cachecontrolmode="UseMaxAge" cachecontrolmaxage="365.00:00:00" />
</staticcontent>
```

As referenced in http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet

How do we do this now in ASP.net 5 when we have no web.config and Startup.cs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Startup.cs > Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, .....)

```
applicationBuilder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
     OnPrepareResponse = context => 
     context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=2592000")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC you can use the [ResponseCacheAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-beta6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ResponseCacheAttribute.cs) on your actions to set client cache headers. There is also a [ResponseCacheFilter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-beta6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ResponseCacheFilter.cs) you can use.

Comment: That's fine for dynamic resources but this is for static files.

Comment: The web.config is till there and used for IIS specific things if I'm not mistaken. Doesn't the <staticContent> element work?

Comment: I just added this as the contents of web.config to the root of wwwroot but still no expires headers :( ... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

What server do you use?

- If you use IIS you can still use web.config in your wwwroot folder.
- If you use kestrel there is no in-built solution yet. However you can write a
  middleware that adds the specific cache-control header. Or use nginx as a reverse proxy.

Middleware:

**NOT tested (!) and just on top of my head** you can write something like this:

```
public sealed class CacheControlMiddleWare
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public CacheControlMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".jpg")
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", new[]{"max-age=100"});
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

nginx as a reverse proxy:

http://mjomaa.com/computer-science/frameworks/asp-net-mvc/141-how-to-combine-nginx-kestrel-for-production-part-i-installation

Beside that, I've wrote some notes for response caching:

http://mjomaa.com/computer-science/frameworks/asp-net-mvc/153-output-response-caching-in-asp-net-5

Comment: Hi Thanks for this. Can you give some insight on how I'd wire-up this middleware in startup.cs (middleware is a new concept for me)